# How to resolve issue with Maven dependencies "Failed to execute goal on project"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, jetty

I have got the following structure in **Eclipse** of my maven projects:

```
MainMavenProject
---MyProject
---MProject-client
---MProject-xyz
---MProject-web
...
```

In Eclipse, I use **JBoss 7.1** to run MProject-web:

[image: JBoss]

Now, I want to run Jetty with another project. From directory **/MainMavenProject/MyProject** I run a command

```
mvn -Djetty:port=8081 jetty:run
```

It has been finished with an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MyProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project ***.*****.MyProject:MyProject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: ***.*****.********:MyProject-client:jar:1.0.
1-SNAPSHOT, com.*****.********:MProject-xyz:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find ***.*****.********:MyProject-client:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT in https://*********.*****.com/nexus/content/groups/development was cached in the local repository, resolutio
n will not be reattempted until the update interval of *****-central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

In MyProject, I use depedencies to the other ones:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.*****.********</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject-client/artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.*****.********</groupId>
    <artifactId>MProject-xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I check, what exactly happend and after that, how to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running `mvn install` on the Main project first.

Your project is missing the other modules, which likely have never been installed to local repository.

Not that you would have to run install every time before running `jetty:run`.

An alternative would be to use the eclipse, right click MyProject -> Run as -> Maven build..., enter `-Djetty:port=8081 jetty:run` in the goals field and check "Resolve workspace artifacts".

Comment: Hi, I did **mvn clean** and I still have the same problem. I prefer to use **jetty** in command line. Can I run **Resolve workspace artifiacts** not from Eclipse ?

Comment: @IWillTryToCodeIt No (at least not without some very dirty tricks). Do **mvn clean install** from **Main project**. Does it work?