# Azure DevOps SaaS Maven build agent issue

Tags: maven, azure-devops, pom.xml, sapjco3

I have a question about the Azure DevOps SaaS Maven build agent issue.

When I run maven build with Azure DevOps SaaS (Windows 2019) Maven build agent, I get the following error message.
I read through the MojoExecutionException guideline, and it seems that the plugin in the POM.xml is causing the issue.

1. How should I know which POM is creating this issue?
2. What would be the guideline for this issue fix?

BTW, the build works well in developer's on-prem Maven build environment

Thank you always for the help!

Build Error

```
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :eorder-base
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>eorder</artifactId>
        <groupId>kr.co.ob.eorder</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>kr.co.ob.eorder.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>eorder-base</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>eorder-base</name>

    <properties>

        <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/servlets.com/cos -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>servlets.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>cos</artifactId>
            <version>05Nov2002</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn</groupId>
            <artifactId>sapjco</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/sapjco3.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>/**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Adding another error message that came above the ones mentioned above
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project eorder-base: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 15 -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command line from your Maven project to see if the issue can be solved.

```
mvn clean install
```

Below are few similar cases as reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22609107/14697693
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27906888/14697693

Comment: The issue was resolved by adding Java 15 in the build pipeline. Thank you.